# How to secure SSH Private key on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, ssh, ssh-keys

I'm using the new ssh client for windows 10 and when trying to connect with a private key I'm getting this error:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions for 'MyPair.pem' are too open. It is required that your
private key files are NOT accessible by others. This private key will
be ignored. Load key "MyPair.pem": bad permissions ec2-user@192.0.2.0:
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I know that if I was on Linux I would need to run `chmod 600` to set the file permissions, but what do you use on Windows 10?

Comment: icacls.exe or powershell Set-Acl or read [this](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/132) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264595/windows-chmod-600)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Keys must only be accessible to the user they're intended for and no other account, service, or group.

- **GUI:** 
   [File] *Properties* → *Security* → *Advanced*

  1. **Owner:** Change → *Select a principal* → Enter key's user → OK
  2. **Permission Entries:** Remove all except for the key's user
  3. **Set key's user to *Full Control* if not already set**

     1. Select user → Modify → Full Control → OK 
         **OR**
     2. Add → *Select a principal* → Enter key's user → OK
  4. OK → OK
- **[`Cmd`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/icacls):**

  ```bash
  ::# Set Key File Variable:
      Set Key="%UserProfile%\.ssh\id_rsa"

  ::# Remove Inheritance:
      Icacls %Key% /c /t /Inheritance:d

  ::# Set Ownership to Owner:
      Icacls %Key% /c /t /Grant %UserName%:F

  ::# Remove All Users, except for Owner:
      Icacls %Key%  /c /t /Remove Administrator BUILTIN\Administrators BUILTIN Everyone System Users

  ::# Verify:
      Icacls %Key%

  ::# Remove Variable:
      set "Key="
  ```
- **[`PowerShell`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/icacls):**

  ```bash
  # Set Key File Variable:
    New-Variable -Name Key -Value "$env:UserProfile\.ssh\id_rsa"

  # Remove Inheritance:
    Icacls $Key /c /t /Inheritance:d

  # Set Ownership to Owner:
    Icacls $Key /c /t /Grant $env:UserName:F

  # Remove All Users, except for Owner:
    Icacls $Key  /c /t /Remove Administrator BUILTIN\Administrators BUILTIN Everyone System Users

  # Verify:
    Icacls $Key

  # Remove Variable:
    Remove-Variable -Name Key
  ```
- **WSL/Cygwin:**

  ```bash
  # Set Variables:
    # Key File:
      key="/path/to/key"

    # User:
      user="$(echo $USER)"

  # Set Ownership to Owner: (assumes user's name is also user's group name)
    chown $user:$user $key

  # Set Access Rights
    chmod 0600 $key

  # Verify
    ls -l $key
  ```

Comment: GUI is not clear / incomplete. Could you please provide further details?

Comment: @Seymour What isn't clear/What are you having issues with?

Comment: That is a bit WAY too generic. It assumes that your remote user is written EXACTLY as the Windows 10 user. 99% improbable in typical scenarios, since Windows has a plethora of users that it needs to work itself (builtin admin, local admin, authenticated users, and so on). That's how security gets bypassed: By making the user too umcomfortable to use it, that he/she will resort to bypass it altogether.

Comment: @alejandrob Remote users must have a Windows account, else there's no `authorized_keys` file to authenticate against, so I'm not understanding the point you're trying to make. Users listed under _"Remove All Users, except for Owner"_ are the default users generally configured with default access to `%UserProfile%` subdirectories/files, so there's no point listing other users, groups, or services, as they don't have default access to `%UserProfile%\.ssh\authorized_keys`.  Only users deviating from the default `authorized_keys` location will need to modify the users to remove access from.

Comment: @JW0914 Indeed. Not just "any" Windows account, but an exactly-named. In my case, Windows arbitrarily decided to name my local user folder as "aleja", and God knows I'm NOT renaming my SSH logins just to to please Windows. It's analogous to a padlock in a knee-high picket-fence: It will harrass only the legitimate owner, while everybody else will just jump over it. I already switched to WAY less cumbersome PuTTYgen.

Comment: @alejandrob That's not factually accurate... it appears you're correlating two entirely different things, or there's a fundamental misunderstanding, as to login to any system running an SSH server, you must have a local account on that system, else how would you log in? `authorized_keys` file is only for logging in remotely to the local account on a system running an SSH server, so I'm not understanding where you're coming from; especially with `PuTTYgen`, which has nothing to do with anything _(it generates SSH keys & `PuTTY` is an SSH client; SSH keys themselves are not tied to a user name)_

Comment: worked via GUI. ran into 'The system cannot find the path specified' errors when running CLI via powershell

Comment: @JW0919 Yes, I did that but it seems to go through a lot files in a recursive manner and emits said error

Comment: @smartexpert It's not operating as expected in PowerShell with `cmd /c` or `cmd /k`, but does within a Cmd terminal, so I've updated the answer with separate PowerShell and Cmd sections - thanks for bringing that to my attention =]

Comment: $env:username correctly returns my username. Icacls $Key /c /t /Grant $env:UserName:F yields error: unknown parameter: "/grant". When spelling out my username instead of using the variable, the command succeeds.

Comment: The powershell script won't delete SIDs of deleted users. I inserted the folllowing code to delete them: # Remove unknown user SIDs:

  New-Variable -Name acl - Value (get-acl $key);
  $acl.Access | Where-Object{
    $_.IdentityReference -like "*S-1*" -and $_.isinherited -like $false} | ForEach-Object{
    $acl.purgeaccessrules($_.IdentityReference);
    Set-Acl -AclObject $acl -path $key;
  }
  Remove-Variable -Name acl

Comment: @jamacoe Please post terminal output on PasteBin, as the code removes all but the owning user if the SSH key(s) are stored where they should be [`$env:UserProfile\.ssh`]. If storing in a non-default location outside of `$env:UserProfile`, you must manually remove all other SIDs that have permissions to wherever that location is, as there are only three users that have access to `$env:UserProfile`: `$env:UserName`, `NT USER\System`, and group: `Administrators` _(the other users listed are the users with generic permissions to most directories outside of `$env:UserProfile`)_

Comment: Very helpful.  Question: why are all the icacls commands using the /t switch which "indicates that this operation is performed on all matching files/directories below the directories specified in the name."?  We're just setting permissions on the key file not *ALL* files recursively.

Comment: @buzz3791 Its because all key files within `.ssh` should generally have the same permissions _(I'm assuming this is the reason why I put it in my answer, but I'd have to take time to read through all the comments again on this answer and several others I answered in the same way - if I discover a different reason, I'll comment back =])_

Answer (score 0):

Using the Windows 10 GUI, here's some additional detail:

1. rightclick the pem file, properties, security.
2. set owner to the key's user (i.e. you)
3. permission entries, remove all users, groups, services except for the key's user
4. set key's user to "full control". Here's how I did it:
5. **disable inheritance**. if you see a popup, choose to convert to explicit permissions on this file.
6. Add, select a principal, object type is User, object name is key's owner's username (for example if your home directory is c:\Users\ben folder, then type ben here). OK.
7. Give that user Full Control
8. delete everyone else (Authenticated users, system, etc)
9. OK

It's important that you set the owner to the key's user before you disable inheritance.

Comment: Isn't this the exact same as the answer above it?

Comment: It has more detail. It should be just a comment to your answer, but superuser.com didn't allow me to add a comment, so the only way I can share the detail is to add as an alternative answer.

Answer (score 0):

To spare time, much easier than the other solutions: just move the file to a "safe location" on your drive, like the `%userprofile%/.ssh` folder.

NOTE: Some people said that it works anyhwere on C: drive, or on the user's downloads folder, but I didn't test that.